# When is the next Taylor Swift concert going to happen?

Tags: live-music, taylor-swift

When is Taylor Swift's next tour going to happen? I know Lover Fest was postponed due to covid, is that going to be rescheduled? Also, will there be a folklore/evermore tour?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's date-specific. Any single answer will eventually be irrelevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the unforseeable future, it's unlikely that Taylor Swift will hold a tour / concerts this year (2022). As [her events page](https://www.taylorswift.com/events) says:

> I love coming on here to tell you good news, or to share a new project with you. It’s not my favorite thing in the world to have to tell you news I’m sad about. I'm so sorry, but I cannot reschedule the shows that we’ve postponed. Although refunds have been available since we first postponed the Lover Fest shows, many of you hung onto your tickets and I too hung onto the idea that we could reschedule.
>
> This is an unprecedented pandemic that has changed everyone’s plans and no one knows what the touring landscape is going to look like in the near future. I’m so disappointed that I won’t be able to see you in person as soon as I wanted to. I miss you terribly and can’t wait til we can all safely be at shows together again.
>
> - Taylor Swift

Answer (score 0):

After releasing her album, *Midnights*, Taylor Swift announced the [Eras Tour](https://www.taylorswift.com/events/) which will begin its US leg in Arizona on March 18, 2023 and run through Augst 2023. This highly-anticipated tour is a "journey through the musical eras of [her] career (past and present!)," Taylor said on Instagram, and will also feature bands (and friends of Taylor's) like Paramore, HAIM, and Phoebe Bridgers. After releasing her video for *Midnights*' *Bejeweled*, many speculate the number of easter eggs also suggests *Speak Now (Taylor's Version)* will drop before the tour begins.